# Question related to Darboux's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Darboux's theorem says that $f'$ has intermediate value property. More precisely,

> ( Darboux's theorem) If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, and if r is any number for which $f'(a)<r<f'(b)$ then $\exists$ c in (a,b) such that $f'(r)=c$.

Thus Darboux's theorem implies that $f'$ cannot have any simple discontinuities on $[a,b].$

I have a question as follows:

> Is there a function $f$ satisfying $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to d} f'(x)=\infty$ for some $d \in (a,b)$ under the assumptions in Darboux's theorem?

If so, I can conclude that for each $x \in (a,b),$ either $(i)$ $f'$ is continuous at $x$ or $(ii)$ $f'$ oscillates near $x.$

It seems that there is no differentiable function $f$ on $[a,b]$ satisfying function $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to d} f'(x)=\infty$ and $\exists f'(d)$ for some $d \in (a,b)$.

Please let me know if you have any idea or comment for my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible that $f'(d)$ exists but $\lim_{x \to d} f'(x)$ fails to exist (oscillating).  It can even be unbounded. An example is $f(x) =x^2 \sin x^{-2} $ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. You just can't have the derivative tend to $\infty$.

Comment: @RRL Thanks for your comment. Now I get to know the information a lot from Darboux theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there can't be.

If $f'(x)\to +\infty$ for $x\to d$, then there will be $\delta$ such that $f'(x) > f'(d)+2$ on $(d, d+\delta)$. And this contradicts Darboux's theorem on $[d,d+\delta/2]$ -- there won't be any place with $f'(x) = f'(d)+1$.

Be a bit careful about the precise meaning of "oscillates" in your conclusion (ii), though. It *is* possible for $f'$ to have a strict global minimum at $d$, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the last paragraph in your answer, you are right. The definition of oscillation  is not clear. By the way, is it possible for $f’$ not to be oscillate? I think, at least one side, $f’$ should oscillate. Is it wrong?

Comment: @0706: That depends on exactly what "oscillate" means here. (I'm not sure if there is a standard definition and if so what it is).

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $x_n \to d \in (a,b)$ from the right, we have

$$f'(d) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n) -f(d)}{x_n - d}$$

By the MVT there is a sequence $\xi_n \in (d,x_n)$ such that

$$f'(d) = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{f(x_n) -f(d)}{x_n - d} = \lim_{n \to \infty} f'(\xi_n)$$

However, if $f'(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to d$, then we must have $f'(\xi_n) \to \infty$  since $\xi_n \to d$, a contradiction.

Hence, your function does not exist.

Comment: Just to verify, the assumptions made here are : $$f'(d) \text{exists}$$ and $$\lim_{x\to d}f(x)=\infty$$ Am I correct?

Comment: @abhishek: Yes — those are the assumptions of OP above after “I have a question as follows:”